# Cравнение двух массивов

Tags: php, javascript, html

Здравствуйте, проблема такая: есть текстовый документ, в котором прописаны названия файлов. И есть папка где эти файлы находятся. При нажатии кнопки у меня выдается массив всех файлов, находящихся в этой папке. Как сделать так, чтобы при этом же формировался второй массив из текстового документа ( получается, что каждая строка - это новый элемент массива) и они сравнивались. Т.е массив из текстового документа и массив всех файлов. Если все ок, то выводилось, что все записи на месте. А если нет, то несовпадающая строка должная удаляться из текстового документа.

Код получения первого массива из всех файлов

```
$dh = opendir('test/');
while ($file = readdir($dh)) :
echo "$file <br>"; endwhile;
closedir($dh);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сравнивать не сами массивы и их элементы, а формировать содержимое файла в виде строки и сравнивать его с текущим содержимым. Получится сравнение одной строки с другой, что быстрее, чем перебор элементов массива.

```
<?php

$dh = opendir('test/');

$arr = [];
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
  if(is_file($file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..') $arr[] = $file;
}
$content = '';
if(count($arr)) {
  // Сохраняем файл с перезаписью, если он изменился
  $content = implode("\n", $arr);
}
if($content != file_get_contents('list.txt')) {
  file_put_contents('list.txt', $content);
  echo "Внесены изменения в список файлов";
} else {
  echo "Все записи на месте";
}

closedir($dh);
```

Comment: $file - я так понял, что нужно указать путь к текстовому файлу, верно?

Comment: А, увидел. Прошу прощения.

Comment: Странно, но почему-то при несовпадении удаляет сразу все содержимое  текстового файла, а не только ту строку, файла которой не существует.

Comment: Да, при несовпадении перезаписывается все содержимое файла, используя переменную $content, в которой мы подготавливаем новое содержимое. Вам все-равно придется файл перезаписывать, или если он каких-то невероятных размеров, формировать рядом копию файла и потом подменять оригинал.

Comment: Просто проверку он выполняет корректно, а вот заменяет почему-то неверно. Сейчас загрузил три файла, проверку они прошли корректно. Дальше удалил один, он перезаписал, вроде бы должно быть все верно, но вот файл оказался пуст весь

Comment: Может я что-то неправильно указал?

Comment: Формат сайта не очень подходящий для дискуссии. Я не могу ответить на вопрос ниже - у меня нет достаточно репутации. Добавить новый ответ тоже не камильфо. Вроде ничего криминального не вижу в ответе дальше, но будьте осторожны с файлами - вы их побить без блокировки может на раз два. Дело в том, что если вы не блокируете к ним доступ, то во время записи может повредить, особенно если обращений много. Крайне настоятельно рекомендуется хранить такую информацию в базе данных - там запросы выстроены в очередь и имеются транзакции. С файлах, особенно в Web работать крайне не тривиально.

Comment: Там еще очень много сюрпризов. Возьмите любое профессиональное приложение - оно с использованием базы данных. Не по тому, что все такие крутые, просто ряд проблем исчезает как класс. Например, не нужно блокировать доступ. Мы с вами этого не делаем, в результате вопрос времени когда файл будет поврежден. Меньше вероятность когда вы один, больше - когда к нему одновременно обращаются несколько запросов.

Answer (score 0):

Код формы:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Загрузка файлов на сервер</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <h2><p><b> Форма для загрузки файлов </b></p></h2>
  <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="filename"><br> 
  <input type="submit" value="Загрузить"><br>
  </form>
   <form action="check.php" method="post" >
  <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Проверка">
  </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Код обработчика upload.php :

```
<?php

   if($_FILES["filename"]["size"] > 1024*8*1024)
   {
     echo ("Размер файла превышает три мегабайта");
     exit;
   }
   // Проверяем загружен ли файл
   if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]))
   {
     // Если файл загружен успешно, перемещаем его
     // из временной директории в конечную
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "files/".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
     echo("Загружен");
   } else {
      echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
   }
   ?>
   </br>
   <?php
   if($f=fopen('list.txt','a')){
         fwrite($f,$_FILES["filename"]["name"]."\n");
         fclose($f);
         echo("Прописан");
         } else {
      echo("Ошибка");

    }

?>
```

Код обработчика check.php

```
<?php


$dh = opendir('files/');

$arr = [];
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
  if(is_file($file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..') $arr[] = $file;
}
$content = '';
if(count($arr)) {
  // Сохраняем файл с перезаписью, если он изменился
  $content = implode("\n", $arr);
}
if($content != file_get_contents('list.txt')) {
  file_put_contents('list.txt', $content);
  echo "Внесены изменения в список файлов";
} else {
  echo "Все записи на месте";
}

closedir($dh);


?>
```